# If Viltrum is a technologically advanced Utopia, what caused the conflict on Viltrum?

Tags: invincible

If Viltrum is a technologically advanced Utopia, what caused the conflict on Viltrum?

Answer (score 4):

This is first addressed in [Invincible #11](https://imagecomics.com/comics/releases/invincible-11).

> The Viltrumites are a naturally violent people.
>
>  [image]

Comment: I would argue that the goal of establishing and expanding a global empire is quite fascist and opposite to a Utopia‍♂️.

Comment: @Raj - 1) Save the image you want to upload to your device. 2) Click on the `Edit` button beneath your answer. 3) Click on the line in your answer where you want the image to go, then click on the `Image` button on the bar at the top of the edit field. 3) Click `Browse` to find the image on your device, then double-click on the image. 4) Click on the `Add picture` button to upload the image to your post. 5) Check the preview to make sure everything looks the way you want it to look, and correct anything that isn't right. 6) Click on the `Save edits` button.

Comment: @Raj - To learn more about how to format images within your posts, click the `Edit` beneath other posts that have images in them to see the type of formatting that other people have used. I regularly post images myself, so you can check my posts out. Just make sure you hit `Cancel` rather than `Save edits` when you're done looking at the formatting. :-)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing the picture with one that's actually legible :-)

Comment: @MCU And You Film Blog   What is the function of the independence and sovereignty of national governments?  To allow them to occasionally fight wars with other national governments, to spread horror and suffering, death and destruction.  The funciton of independent and sovereign natinal govrnments is to kill. Every independent nation is a thing that must not be, a thing that must be abolished.